# window onload event fails in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, onload

I'm adding some `<script/>` tags from javascript to load some libraries (e.g., jquery). When all libraries are loaded, I execute main code. To wait until everything's ready, I use solution similar to the one in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559150/best-practice-for-using-window-onload/559161#559161) (found it on the web).

Now, the story: http://jsfiddle.net/EH84z/

```
function load_javascript(src) {
    var a = document.createElement('script');
    a.type = 'text/javascript';
    a.src = src;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(a, s);
}

load_javascript('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js');

function addEvent(elm, evType, fn, useCapture) {
    //Credit: Function written by Scott Andrews
    //(slightly modified)
    var ret = 0;

    if (elm.addEventListener) {
        ret = elm.addEventListener(evType, fn, useCapture);
    } else if (elm.attachEvent) {
        ret = elm.attachEvent('on' + evType, fn);
    } else {
        elm['on' + evType] = fn;
    }

    return ret;
}

addEvent(window, "load", function() {
    console.log(window.jQuery + '  ' + window.$);
    $(document);
}, false);
```

It works fine in Firefox, but quite often fails in Chrome. Every second time I press jsfiddle 'run' button, callback is executed before JQuery is loaded, thus giving error in Chrome console.

Does it mean I misuse `addEventListener` horribly? If yes, what's the correct use for it and how do I *really* wait until all scripts are loaded?

Thanks!
PS Didn't test it in any other browsers yet, so please comment if it's failing somewhere else.

**edit**
if I wait one second (using `setTimout`) before testing, success rate increases to 100%. An example http://jsfiddle.net/EH84z/1/

Comment: Just curious, why are you trying to load a framework dynamically?

Comment: @Nick It's a widget which people insert in their pages. I could give them few _script_ tags and tell to put them into _head_ element, but I image it's less confusing for the user when everything happens under the hood.

Comment: Sounds like you are hitting this bug http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/4196

Comment: What if jQuery's already being loaded elsewhere? Including it again will blow away any plugins they have....sometimes a dependency (like *most* jQuery plugins specify) is a better option.

Comment: @Nick I don't load it again if it's already present. But I'll check out dependency mechanism, thanks.

Comment: Also use a feature set that's older if possible, 1.3 or 1.2 at worst (though 1.3+ would be ok) unless you're depending on 1.4+ features somehow...users can't include multiple versions, so it's best to rely on one version behind to support as many as possible, but hey if you need 1.4+ functionality then that's how it goes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to attach the `load` event to the jQuery script tag, not the `window` object.

Try this:

```
function load_javascript(src) {
    var a = document.createElement('script');
    a.type = 'text/javascript';
    a.src = src;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(a, s);

    // attach it to the script tag
    addEvent(a, "load", function() {
        console.log(window.jQuery + '  ' + window.$);
        $(document);
    }, false);
}
```

Comment: Was just looking up the script load event. You beat me to it. +1

Comment: does it differ if you attach the event *first* and then set the src property?

Comment: +1, thanks! I can certainly use one event listener for each script/link tag. But there's another question then: what's the use for window's 'load' event? It's mentioned in lots of places (e.g., the answer I linked). What does it do, then?

Comment: @Nikita: The load event on the window object is fired when all resources (the document, objects, images, css, etc) have finished rendering... the one's in the HTML... not the ones you add dynamically. You probably need to call your `load_javascript()` when the window has fired the load event... you can't manipulate the DOM until it is loaded.