# jquery - iframe access denied in IE on some pages

Tags: jquery, iframe, printing, printthis

I'm the author of printThis, a jquery plugin for printing.

https://github.com/jasonday/printThis

I have a user that has brought up an issue, that I have been unable to crack and unfortunately, I am unable to share the page (privacy concerns).

On the user's site, the issue presents on some pages in IE, but not others. The print is failing to happen, as the iframe remains empty.

The error in IE is within jQuery:

```
contents: function (a) {
            return f.nodeName(a,
                "iframe") ? a.contentDocument || a.contentWindow.document : f.makeArray(a.childNodes)
        }
```

Using logging, I was able to determine it was failing around this line:

```
var $doc = $("#" + strFrameName).contents();
```

But again, this only happens on some pages and I have been unable to recreate in any instance outside of this user's site.

My question: Is there a better approach here? or a method to make the `$doc` object more bulletproof?

---

```
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
// printThis v1.1
// Printing plug-in for jQuery
//
// Resources (based on) :
//              jPrintArea: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jPrintArea
//              jqPrint: https://github.com/permanenttourist/jquery.jqprint
//              Ben Nadal: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1591-Ask-Ben-Print-Part-Of-A-Web-Page-With-jQuery.htm
//
// Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
//              http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
//              http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
//
// (c) Jason Day 2012
//
// Usage:
//
// $("#mySelector").printThis({
//      debug: false, //show the iframe for debugging
//      importCSS: true, // import page CSS
//      printContainer: true, // grab outer container as well as the contents of the selector
//      loadCSS: "path/to/my.css" //path to additional css file
//  });
//
// Notes:
//  - the loadCSS option does not need @media print
//------------------------------------------------------------------------

(function($) {
    var opt;

    $.fn.printThis = function (options) {
        opt = $.extend({}, $.fn.printThis.defaults, options);

        var $element = (this instanceof jQuery) ? this : $(this);

    // if Opera, open a new tab
        if ($.browser.opera)
        {
            var tab = window.open("","Print Preview");
            tab.document.open();


        }
    // add dynamic iframe to DOM
        else
        {
        var strFrameName = ("printThis-" + (new Date()).getTime());

            var $iframe = $("<iframe id='" + strFrameName +"' src='about:blank'/>");

            if (!opt.debug) { $iframe.css({ position: "absolute", width: "0px", height: "0px", left: "-600px", top: "-600px" }); }

            $iframe.appendTo("body");

        }
    // allow iframe to fully render before action
    setTimeout ( function () {

        if ($.browser.opera)
            {
        var $doc = tab.document;
        } else
        {
        var $doc = $("#" + strFrameName).contents();
        }



        // import page css
        if (opt.importCSS)
        {
                $("link[rel=stylesheet]").each(function(){
                var href = $(this).attr('href');
                if(href){
                        var media = $(this).attr('media') || 'all';
                        $doc.find("head").append("<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='" + href + "' media='"+media+"'>");
                    }
        });
        }

        // add another stylesheet
        if (opt.loadCSS)
        {
        $doc.find("head").append("<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='" + opt.loadCSS + "'>");

        }

        //add title of the page
        if (opt.titlePage)
        {
        $doc.find("head").append('<title>'+opt.titlePage+'</title>');
        } 
        //grab outer container
        if (opt.printContainer) { $doc.find("body").append($element.outer()); }
        else { $element.each( function() { $doc.find("body").append($(this).html()); }); }

        //$doc.close();
        // print
        ($.browser.opera ? tab : $iframe[0].contentWindow).focus();
        setTimeout( function() { ($.browser.opera ? tab : $iframe[0].contentWindow).print(); if (tab) { tab.close(); } }, 1000);

        //removed iframe after 60 seconds
        setTimeout(
        function(){
        $iframe.remove();
        },
        (60 * 1000)
        );
    }, 333 );
    }


    $.fn.printThis.defaults = {
        debug: false, //show the iframe for debugging
        importCSS: true, // import page CSS
        printContainer: true, // grab outer container as well as the contents of the selector
        loadCSS: "", //path to additional css file
        titlePage: "" //add title to print page
    };


    jQuery.fn.outer = function() {
      return $($('<div></div>').html(this.clone())).html();
    }
})(jQuery);
```

**UPDATE**

Issue to due to `document.domain`

This type of page has `document.domain` set and IE does not inherit `document.domain` from the parent.

To fix that portion, I changed the iframe creation to standard javascript and set the source to write `document.domain` on iframe creation.

```
    var printI= document.createElement('iframe');

    printI.name = "printIframe";

    printI.id = strFrameName;

    document.body.appendChild(printI);

    printI.src = "javascript:document.write('<head><script>document.domain=\"mydomain.com\";</script></head><body></body>')";


   var $iframe = $("#" + strFrameName);
```

So this fixes the access denied, however now the frame won't print. I've tried a lot of different methods for accessing the object, however none of them are working.

A) how would you access the frame in this scenario (i've tried most of the methods outlined on SO) to get IE to recognize and print

or

B) can anyone think of a better way to get the document.domain into the iframe on creation with jQuery? (can't be afterwards, as the access denied issue will come up)

Comment: Are all pages in the same domain/sub-domain?

Comment: @Christophe - yes. All pages are within the same domain. The print isn't working specifically on one type of page, but works on all others.

Comment: Might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe

Comment: also check if your script user use same version of jQuery or not, sometimes different version of jQuery break things down, i have experienced this once when i try to upgrade my jQuery to the latest version, and a few things just break down, so i just revert to the old one

Comment: @am05mhz - unfortunately, it's not the jquery version. I've tested all versions back to 1.4.2

Comment: Are the pages fully and normally loaded in the iframe? Does this happen in all ie versions?

Comment: Jason, your print plugin is just great! It's missing the javascript integration (importation). Sometimes you need to rerun some code to make outline properly ordered (e.g. When using Masory). I managed to do it with simply escaping `<script>` and doing it with  something like this: `var script = '<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/global.js"></scr' + 'ipt>';`. It's important that the plugin not only gets parent's page `.js` but also let to pass custom

Comment: script functionality, like `var scriptCurPage = '<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript">$("#documents_container").masonry({ columnWidth: 500, itemSelector: ".item"});});</scr' + 'ipt>';'`

Later you `just document.write(script); document.write(scriptCurPage);` and you got it! This will make your plugin standout as non of them have script functionality.

Comment: thanks this post helped me on my problem.. the document.domain is crazy.. it dont recognize example.com is the same as www.example.com and I get wrongdocument error all the time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue is due to IE not inheriting the parent document.domain.

Unfortunately, once you get into this murky area, it took some specific hacks to get this to work properly.

Basically doing a check for if document.domain is being explicitly set and the browser is IE.

Full updated plugin:

https://github.com/jasonday/printThis

```
(function ($) {
    var opt;
    $.fn.printThis = function (options) {
        opt = $.extend({}, $.fn.printThis.defaults, options);
        var $element = this instanceof jQuery ? this : $(this);

            var strFrameName = "printThis-" + (new Date()).getTime();

            if(window.location.hostname !== document.domain && navigator.userAgent.match(/msie/i)){
                // Ugly IE hacks due to IE not inheriting document.domain from parent
                // checks if document.domain is set by comparing the host name against document.domain
                var iframeSrc = "javascript:document.write(\"<head><script>document.domain=\\\"" + document.domain + "\\\";</script></head><body></body>\")";
                var printI= document.createElement('iframe');
                printI.name = "printIframe";
                printI.id = strFrameName;
                printI.className = "MSIE";
                document.body.appendChild(printI);
                printI.src = iframeSrc;

            } else {
                 // other browsers inherit document.domain, and IE works if document.domain is not explicitly set
                var $frame = $("<iframe id='" + strFrameName +"' name='printIframe' />");
                $frame.appendTo("body");
            }


            var $iframe = $("#" + strFrameName);

            // show frame if in debug mode
            if (!opt.debug) $iframe.css({
                position: "absolute",
                width: "0px",
                height: "0px",
                left: "-600px",
                top: "-600px"
            });


        // $iframe.ready() and $iframe.load were inconsistent between browsers    
        setTimeout ( function () {

            var $doc = $iframe.contents();

            // import page stylesheets
            if (opt.importCSS) $("link[rel=stylesheet]").each(function () {
                var href = $(this).attr("href");
                if (href) {
                    var media = $(this).attr("media") || "all";
                    $doc.find("head").append("<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='" + href + "' media='" + media + "'>")
                }
            });

            //add title to iframe
            if (opt.pageTitle) $doc.find("head").append("<title>" + opt.pageTitle + "</title>");

            // import additional stylesheet
            if (opt.loadCSS) $doc.find("head").append("<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='" + opt.loadCSS + "'>");

            // grab $.selector as container
            if (opt.printContainer) $doc.find("body").append($element.outer());

            // otherwise just print interior elements of container
            else $element.each(function () {
                $doc.find("body").append($(this).html())
            });

            if($iframe.hasClass("MSIE")){
                // check if the iframe was created with the ugly hack
                // and perform another ugly hack out of neccessity
                window.frames["printIframe"].focus();
                setTimeout(function () {
                   $doc.find("head").append("<script>  window.print(); </script>");
                }, 500 );
            } else {
                // proper method
                $iframe[0].contentWindow.focus();
                $iframe[0].contentWindow.print();  
            }

             //remove iframe after print
            if (!opt.debug) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $iframe.remove();
                }, 1000);
            }


        }, 333 );

    };

    // defaults
    $.fn.printThis.defaults = {
        debug: false,           // show the iframe for debugging
        importCSS: true,        // import parent page css
        printContainer: true,   // print outer container/$.selector
        loadCSS: "",            // load an additional css file
        pageTitle: ""           // add title to print page
    };

    // $.selector container
    jQuery.fn.outer = function () {
        return $($("<div></div>").html(this.clone())).html()
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 7):

In your code, you are using `setTimeout` to execute your function after the iframe has loaded.

```
// allow iframe to fully render before action
setTimeout ( function () {
...
}, 333 );  //333ms
```

but this is a mistake as you don't know if the time given is enough to load the iframe or not. Javascript execution is asynchronous so, there is no guarantee that `setTimeout` will offset the execution of the function until iframe loads. Since load time is different for different pages. Some cannot execute the code properly, pointing to the line which you find to be causing errors.

```
var $doc = $("#" + strFrameName).contents();  //only after loading
```

The correct way is to use event `load` or `onload` to get to know if the DOM object has loaded properly or not.

```
<script>
document.getElementById("myframe").onload = function() {
  alert("myframe is loaded");
};
</script>
//or
<iframe id="myFrame" onload="myFunction();"></iframe>
```

Comment: chrome isn't recognizing the onload event

Comment: chrome handles it differently, see here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889173/window-onload-event-fails-in-chrome and https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/django-users/FwLRFzFImVU

Comment: @user568109 This plugin is missing `<script>` importation? Please see question's additional comments! What do you think? I try to use it in my current project as it's the only way to reload Masonry! It works perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

As long as you set iframe src, the same origin has to be verified against parent element, even if you set it as 'about:blank'. I guess IE fails in proper checkng, or some javascript ran and set the document.location to different one than the iframe is created.

How about NOT setting src at all like the following? it still should work.

```
var $iframe = $("<iframe id='" + strFrameName +"'/>");
$iframe.appendTo("body");
var $iframeDoc = $iframe[0].contentWindow.document;

$iframeDoc.open();
$iframeDoc.write("foo");
$iframeDoc.close();
```

Comment: This helped me with a similar issue - I wasn't able to get the iframe body element until I did $('iframe')[0].contentWindow.document.open().

Answer (score 0):

IE works with iframe like all the other browsers (at least for main functions). You just have to keep a set of rules:

- before you load any javascript in the iframe (that part of js which needs to know about the iframe parent), ensure that the parent has document.domain changed.
- when all iframe resources are loaded, change document.domain to be the same as the one defined in parent. (You need to do this later because setting domain will cause the iframe resource's request to fail)
- now you can make a reference for parent window: var winn =  window.parent
- now you can make a reference to parent HTML, in order to manipulate it:
  var parentContent = $('html', winn.document)
- at this point you should have access to IE parent window/document and you can change it as you wont

Comment: Please don't copy/paste the same [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886547/access-is-denied-javascript-error-when-trying-to-access-the-document-object-of/35539021#35539021) to multiple questions. Instead, each answer should be customized to the specific question being asked instead of a generic copy and paste.

Answer (score 0):

This answer has already been stated in the original question UPDATE, but I wanted add a more succinct answer to the original question related to getting around the SCRIPT70 Permission denied error (I ran into this on IE11/Win7 with JQuery 3.2.1).

Instead of `$('<iframe .../>').appendTo($('body'))`

Do this:

```
var $iframe = $('<iframe .../>');
document.body.appendChild($iframe[0]);
```

Answer taken from here: https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13936#comment:28