# Javascript: access denied when access iframe with "about:blank" source

Tags: javascript, jquery

We are seeing the issue on a customer's machine: a "Access Denied" error Randomly show up when the JS code try to access an iframe content by using:

```
var frameContents = $('#IFRAME2').contents();
```

According to our customer's steps, I'm sure that at that time, the src of the iframe is still "about:Blank" like it was set by default:

```
<iframe id="IFRAME2" src="about:blank" style="width: 100%;"></iframe>
```

Since this is a "Sometimes" issue and does not happen on all of the machines, we could not reproduce it on our lab and don't know how to fix it properly.

My question: What can cause this issue? Any idea to fix it?

Update: My customer said that they didn't see the issue until they upgrade their IE from 8 to 11. OS is windows 7 SP1 French.

Comment: This might help.It could be Cross Domain Access [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378433/how-do-i-implement-cross-domain-url-access-from-an-iframe-using-javascript)

Comment: @SatejS Thank you. But I believe this is not a cross domain issue because the src of iframe is blank and the domain of the parent page is not explicit set.

Comment: Is your client using IE ? What is the OS ?

Comment: @AkshayArora I updated the question.

Comment: Considering it's IE, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15210205/4759033) too.

Comment: @SatejS I checked it but I think that's not my issue because I didn't explicitly set the document.domain anywhere

Comment: If you set your http header yourself, make sure X-Frame-Options is either NONE or SAMEORIGIN.