# Display the current date in an ASP.NET label with C# and JS

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, vwdexpress

I'm trying to display the current date in an ASP.NET label using JavaScript and C#.  Here's what I have:

C#:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Type.GetType("System.String"), "addScript", "GetDate()", true);
}
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetDate() 
    {
        var dt = new Date();
        var element = document.getElementById("MainContent_FormView1_Label1");

        element.text = dt.toDateString();
    }
</script>
```

ASP.NET:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Date", "{0:d}") %>'></asp:Label>
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?  Also, can the JS be run when the page loads without using the C# Page_Load method?  I picked up the RegisterStartupScript [elsewhere](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/200555/How-to-Show-Date-in-Label-using-Javascript.aspx) but I don't really understand it.

Thanks,
Liam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `element.innerText = dt.toDateString();` instead.

Also, you don't need to use `RegisterStartupScript`. You can just call the `getDate()` function in the `onLoad` event.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = function(){
        getDate();
    };

    function getDate() 
    {
        var dt = new Date();
        var element = document.getElementById("MainContent_FormView1_Label1");

        element.text = dt.toDateString();
    }
</script>
```

However, you might want to read [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559150/best-practice-for-using-window-onload) for best practice in using `window.onload`, or consider using a framework such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and its [`document.ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: @Liam if Geoff's answer solved it you should mark it as the answer

Comment: @Liam. Thanks. You're right. There is a short time limit before you can accept answers...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//C#
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "addScript", "GetDate()", true);
}

//JS
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetDate() 
    {
        var dt = new Date();
        var element = document.getElementById("<%# Label1.ClientID %>");

        element.innerHTML = dt.toDateString();
    }
</script>

//ASP.Net
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=''></asp:Label>
```

Comment: Whenever I tried to use the <% Label1.ClientID %>, I got a "; expected" error on that line (not column number).  Any idea why that is?

Comment: @Liam, you forgot the pound sign. It's <%# Label1.ClientID %>, not <% Label1.ClientID %>.

Answer (score 0):

You can change Your `PageLoad` to `OnPreInit` and also you can change your JS to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function GetDate()
  {
     document.getElementById('<%Label1.ClientID%>').value = new Date().toDateString(); 
 }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set as

```
Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

EDIT

If you don't want to set the DateTime in serverside. You can use the below code without any `onload` or `RegisterStartupScript` methods

```
<asp:Label ID="label1" runat="server" />

<!-- At the end of ASPX Page -->

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("MainContent_FormView1_Label1").innerHTML = new Date().toDateString()
</script>
```

Comment: I'm using the Text attribute to bind this label to a database.  I don't think I can use your solution at the same time.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pagemethods , so that you can Display Time Eventually

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <title>jQuery to call page methods in ASP.NET</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js">  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="Form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager EnablePageMethods="true" ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            setInterval(setTime, 1000);
            function setTime() {
                PageMethods.getTime(function(res) {
                    document.title = res;
                    $('#time').html(res);
                });
            };
        });
    </script>
    Time : <span id='time'></span>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Services;
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }
    [WebMethod]
    public static string getTime()
    {
        return DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt");
    }

}
```