# Two window.onload on the site

Tags: javascript

I use window.onload in the my script which contains other call functions

```
window.onload = function() {
            maxHeight_main_column();
...
}
```

and added my script in the head tag

In the body I added new script from  other site which uses window.onload again, and my  window.onload works good but second window.onload doesn't work, how I can resolve this problem?

I can't edit  second file with window.onlad

Comment: Use `function func(){/*onloadcodehere*/};if (window.addEventListener)window.addEventListener('load',func,true);else window.attachEvent('onload', func);`

Comment: Use jquery. You can have as many `$(document).ready()` blocks as you want. Directly messing with `window.onload` is painful when multiple code blocks are trying to register their startup functions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best practice for using window.onload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559150/best-practice-for-using-window-onload)

Comment: That is why everybody told you not to use the old event handling model (`.onclick` & co, and their inline HTML friends).

Comment: @bazmegakapa `window.onload` has one big advantage: You can control the order of execution. Besides that, who said it should not be used?

Comment: @Pumbaa80 Can't you do the same with the advanced model? In that case why would you stick to the old one (stubbornness is not an answer)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There can only be one function assigned to `window.onload`.  But, you can have multiple event listeners that listen to that same event.

```
// cross browser way to add an event listener
function addListener(event, obj, fn) {
    if (obj.addEventListener) {
        obj.addEventListener(event, fn, false);   // modern browsers
    } else {
        obj.attachEvent("on"+event, fn);          // older versions of IE
    }
}

addListener('load', window, myFunc1);    // you can have multiple ones of these
addListener('load', window, myFunc2);    // you can have multiple ones of these
window.onload = myFunc3;                 // one and only one of these
```

See the [MDN doc on addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) for more details.

In your specific case, you can use this code for your onload handler and let the other one use `window.onload`:

```
// cross browser way to add an event listener
function addListener(event, obj, fn) {
    if (obj.addEventListener) {
        obj.addEventListener(event, fn, false);   // modern browsers
    } else {
        obj.attachEvent("on"+event, fn);          // older versions of IE
    }
}
addListener('load', window, function() {
    maxHeight_main_column();
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the next function to add multiple `onLoad` listeners (copied from [here](http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/onloads/index.html)):

```
function addLoadEvent(func) {
  var oldonload = window.onload;
  if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
    window.onload = func;
  } else {
    window.onload = function() {
      if (oldonload) {
        oldonload();
      }
      func();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -5):

Include jQuery and use this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    maxHeight_main_column();
})
```

Comment: This is not the same event, the OP didn't suggest jQuery, and your demo contains a syntax error. Three reasons for a downvote.

Comment: Your code still contains a syntax error, is not equivalent to `window.onload`. Reply to comment: jQuery is not necessary for binding `window.onload` events, because it can be easily achieved without. Loading a whole library, just for `onload` is not a good practice.

Comment: @x10 Somebody said he had seen a website that had no jQuery included. I still wonder how it was working? Might that be magic?

Comment: A good answer to "how it was working" might be "differently on every browser"

Comment: @x10 I'm a big fan of jQuery. But if someone asks a question about the DOM event model, the answer is not jQuery.

Comment: Right, as we see from the selected answer, the right thing to do is to copy the jQuery functionality.

Comment: @x10 That solution is much older than jQuery itself.