# confused on how to re-use this javascript function

Tags: javascript, css

So I have a function that registers all the buttons above a textarea, to insert bbcode into that textarea. It works perfectly fine, until I have more than one of these editors on the same page.

Example here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JWOzZj

You will see in that example, the second editor's buttons work, but the first does not as it seems to overwrite everything into the last editor made.

I'm not too great with JS, so I'm hoping it's something simple to allow it to be re-used.

Here's the JS code:

```
/*
 * Forked from Octus Editor: https://github.com/julianrichen/octus-editor MIT license
 */
function OctusEditor(editor_id) 
{
    var editor_bar = 'bar_' + editor_id;
    var this_editor = document.getElementById(editor_id);
    /*
     * init()
     *
     * Start editor
     */
    function init() 
    {
        var quotes  = document.querySelectorAll('[data-quote]');

        // Register tags
        registerElements(editor_bar);

        // Register all possible quotes.
        for (var x = 0; x < quotes.length; x++) 
        {
            quotes[x].addEventListener("click", registerQuote, false);
        }
    }

    /*
     * registerElements()
     *
     * Register all tags from each editor
     */
    function registerElements(id) 
    {
        // Get all styles
        var tags    = document.querySelectorAll('#' + editor_bar + ' .styles ul li[data-tag]'),
            snippet = document.querySelectorAll('#' + editor_bar + ' .styles ul li[data-snippet]');
        // register all the tags
        for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) 
        {
            // Log editor id
            tags[i].editor_id = id;
            // Add click event
            tags[i].addEventListener("click", registerTag, false);
        }

        // register all the snippets
        for (var x = 0; x < snippet.length; x++) 
        {
            // Log editor id
            snippet[x].editor_id = id;
            // Add click event
            snippet[x].addEventListener("click", registerSnippet, false);
        }
    }

    /*
     * registerTag()
     *
     * Get tag from each editor
     */
    function registerTag() 
    {
        // Get textarea
        var dataTag = this.dataset.tag;

        // Do we have a sub class?
        if(this.dataset.subtag) 
        {
            // Fire tag
            createTag(dataTag, this.dataset.subtag);
        } 
        else 
        {
            // Fire tag
            createTag(dataTag);
        }
    }

    /*
     * registerSnippet()
     *
     * Get tag from each editor
     */
    function registerSnippet() 
    {       
        // Fire snippet
        snippet(this.dataset.snippet);
    }

    /*
     * registerQuote()
     *
     * Register all quotes
     */
    function registerQuote() 
    {
        var username = this.dataset.quote;
        var text = this.dataset.comment;
        quote(text, username);
    }

    /*
     * quote()
     *
     * Insert a quote, decodeEntities sorts out the html for the textarea
     */
     function decodeEntities(encodedString)
     {
         var textArea = document.createElement('textarea');
         textArea.innerHTML = encodedString;
         return textArea.value;
     }

     function quote(text, name)
     {
         text = decodeEntities(text);

         content = "[quote=" + name + "]" + text;
         content += "[/quote]";

         this_editor.value += content;
     }

    /*
     * bbcode()
     *
     * Insert tag
     */
    function createTag(tag, subtag) 
    {
        var selected,
            ins,
            sel,
            popUpData;
        // Add a sub tag?
        if (typeof subtag != 'undefined') 
        {
            subtag = '=' + subtag;
        } 
        else 
        {
            subtag = '';
        }

        this_editor.focus();

        if (typeof this_editor.selectionStart != 'undefined') 
        {
            selected = this_editor.value.slice(this_editor.selectionStart, this_editor.selectionEnd);
        } 
        else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != 'Control') // for IE compatibility
        { 
            selected = document.selection.createRange().text;
        }

        popUpData = popUp(tag, subtag, selected);
        if(popUpData === null || typeof popUpData == 'undefined') 
        {
            return;
        }
        tag      = popUpData[0];
        subtag   = popUpData[1];
        selected = popUpData[2];
        ins = '[' + tag + '' + subtag + ']' + selected + '[/' + tag +']';
        if (!document.execCommand("insertText", false, ins)) 
        {
            this_editor.value = this_editor.value.slice(0, this_editor.selectionStart) + ins + this_editor.value.slice(this_editor.selectionEnd);
        }
    }

    /*
     * snippet()
     *
     * Insert snippet
     */
    function snippet(tag) 
    {
        var selected,
            ins,
            sel;

        this_editor.focus();

        if (typeof this_editor.selectionStart != 'undefined') 
        {
            selected = this_editor.value.slice(this_editor.selectionStart, this_editor.selectionEnd);
        } 
        else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != 'Control') // for IE compatibility
        { 
            selected = document.selection.createRange().text;
        }

        popUpData = popUp(tag, selected);
        if(popUpData === null || typeof popUpData == 'undefined') 
        {
            return;
        }
        tag      = popUpData[0];
        selected = popUpData[1];
        ins = tag + selected;
        if (!document.execCommand("insertText", false, ins)) 
        {
            this_editor.value = this_editor.value.slice(0, this_editor.selectionStart) + ins + this_editor.value.slice(this_editor.selectionEnd);
        }
    }

    /*
     * getYouTubeID()
     *
     * Get YouTube ID
     */
     function getYouTubeID(input)
     {
        var id;

        var this_button = document.getElementById('youtube-bbcode');
        var yt_limit = this_button.getAttribute('data-limit');

        if(input === "") 
        {
            input = window.prompt('Enter YouTube URL, limited to ' + yt_limit + ' per post');
        }
        id = input.match(/(?:youtube\.com\/(?:[^\/]+\/.+\/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)\/|.*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be\/)([^"&?\/ ]{11})/i);
        if(id === null) 
        {
            return null;
        }
        return id[1];
    }

    /*
     * popUp()
     *
     * Checks if a pop-up needs to be called
     */
    function popUp(tag, subtag, selected) 
    {
        var data;

        if(tag == 'youtube') 
        {
            selected = getYouTubeID(selected);
            if(selected === null) 
            {
                return null;
            }
        } 
        else if(tag == 'url' && selected != "") 
        {
            subtag = window.prompt('Enter a valid URL');
            if(subtag === null || subtag === '') 
            {
                return null;
            } 
            else 
            {
                subtag = '=' + subtag;
            }
        } 
        else if(tag == 'url' && selected === "") 
        {
            subtag = window.prompt('Enter a valid URL');
            if(subtag === null || subtag === '') 
            {
                return null;
            } 
            else 
            {
                subtag = '=' + subtag;
            }
            selected = window.prompt('URL link text');
            if(selected === null || selected === '') 
            {
                selected = 'link';
            }
        }

        data = [tag, subtag, selected];

        return data;
    }

    /*
     * Allow keyboard shortcut
     *
     * All people to use keyboard shortcut
     */
    document.onkeydown = function(e) 
    {
        var field = document.getElementById(editor_id);
        if (field === document.activeElement)
        {
            var key = e.keyCode || e.which;
            if (e.ctrlKey) 
            {
                switch (key) 
                {
                    //http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/00000520.html
                    case 66: // Ctrl+B
                        e.preventDefault();
                        createTag(field, 'b');
                        break;
                    case 73: // Ctrl+I
                        e.preventDefault();
                        createTag(field, 'i');
                        break;
                    case 85: // Ctrl+U
                        e.preventDefault();
                        createTag(field, 'u');
                        break;
                    case 76: // CTRL+L
                        e.preventDefault();
                        createTag(field, 'url');
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    };

    // Init
    init();
}
```

And the HTML of the form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    OctusEditor('test');
};
</script>
    <div id="bar_test" class="octus-editor group">
            <div class="styles group">
                <ul>
                <li data-tag="b" class="bold" accesskey="B">B</li>
                <li data-tag="i" class="italic" accesskey="I">I</li>
                <li data-tag="u" class="underline" accesskey="U">U</li>
                <li data-tag="s" class="strike">S</li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                <li data-tag="img">img</li>
                <li data-tag="url">url</li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                <li data-tag="code">code</li>
                <li data-tag="quote">quote</li>
                <li data-tag="spoiler">spoiler</li>
                </ul>
        </div>
            <div class="textarea group">
                <textarea name="{:name}" rows="3" cols="17" id="test"></textarea>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine your onload functions:

```
window.onload = function() {
    OctusEditor('test');
    OctusEditor('test2');
};
```

**[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QpOoJx)**

Comment: Thanks, thought it was something dumb! Is there a better way to do that? It's generated by the PHP from a template with that JS onload at the top, so it's always split. Wondering if there's a nicer way?

Comment: Well you'd need to combine the window.onloads as subsequent calls override the previous ones (as you saw). You'd need to either combine them or remove them from the onload and call them at the end of the page once everything has loaded. For example, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330102/two-window-onload-on-the-the-site and http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3724571/Using-Multiple-JavaScript-Onload-Functions.htm

Comment: Yeah you're right, I've just combined them and put them in the footer template so I don't need onload now :)