# Problems adding a new element to the DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom

Trying to add a new element to the DOM but I get all sorts of errors depending on what I try to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/pRVAd/

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        var newElement = document.createElement("pre");
        var newText = document.createTextNode("Contents of the element");
        newElement.appendChild(newText);
        document.getElementsByTag("body").appendChild(newElement);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Welcome</p>
</body>

</html>​
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script is in the `<head>` and your code runs immediately (it is not a delayed function call). The `<body>` does not exist when you try to run it.

**Move the script to just before `</body>`** or move it into a function and call it `onload`.

`getElementsByTag` is not a method on the `document` object. You probably mean `getElementsByTagName` but that returns a NodeList, not an HTMLElementNode. This is like an array. You need to pull the first item off it, or better:

**Use `document.body`**

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want:

```
   <html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var newElement = document.createElement("pre");
            var newText = document.createTextNode("Contents of the element");
            newElement.appendChild(newText);
            document.body.appendChild(newElement);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Welcome</p>
    </body>
```

and here is [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KdxMt/)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this new Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pRVAd/1/

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function doTheThing() {
            var newElement = document.createElement("pre");
            var newText = document.createTextNode("Contents of the element");
            newElement.appendChild(newText);
            document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(newElement);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Do The Thing" onclick="doTheThing()">    
    <p>Welcome</p>
</body>

<html>​
```

The correct sintax is: `document.getElementsByTagName("TagName")[index]`

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    // This function will be executed once that the DOM tree is finalized
    // (the page has finished loading)
    window.onload = function() {
      var newElement = document.createElement("pre");
      var newText = document.createTextNode("Contents of the element");
      newElement.appendChild(newText);
      // You have to use document.body instead of document.getElementsByTag("body")
      document.body.appendChild(newElement);  
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Welcome</p>
</body>
</html>​
```

[`window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onload) and [how to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559150/best-practice-for-using-window-onload) [use it correctly](http://roberthahn.ca/articles/2007/02/02/how-to-use-window-onload-the-right-way/).

[`document.body`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.body)