# Simple impress.js does not work

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow, impress.js

Somehow even the simplest ground up impress.js slide does not work for me :( http://dl.dropbox.com/u/655237/events/GTG.zip … , Always have to use your example.

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Impress Demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="impress">
            <div id="start">
                    <p style='width:1000px;font-size:80px;
                text-align:center'>Creating Stunning Visualizations</p>
                <p>Impress.js </p>
                </div>

            <div id="slide2" data-x="-1200" data-y="0">
                    <p style='width:1000px;font-size:80px;'>
                First Slide Moves From Left To Right</p>
                <p>Impress.js </p>
                </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">impress().init();</script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/impress.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And I have the impress.js file under the js directory.Still none of the latest browser show the slides . I am using firefox 16.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're calling impress before loading the library, try switching the order of your script tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/impress.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">impress().init();</script>
```

Alternatively use a ready handler function to initialise your page scripts, like `window.onload` or jquery's `ready()`.  For more on this see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559150/best-practice-for-using-window-onload).

Also, going by the [impress examples](https://github.com/bartaz/impress.js/blob/master/index.html), in the simplest case each step of the presentation should be an element inside the `#impress` element with a class name of `step`.

Comment: You are right , the order was wrong. Also I had to add class="step slide" to every slide div. I wonder why I did not see that :|