# How to get client current date and time in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

I have a hidden field in my master page. And I set the current date and time as a value in that "hiddenfield" using Javascript. I am unable to get this hidden field value in any other page's page load method.

Here is my code.

```
HiddenField hdnCurrentDate = (HiddenField)this.Master.FindControl("hdnCurrentDate");
                ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Message", "var CurrentDate = new Date(); $('#" + hdnCurrentDate.ClientID + "').val(CurrentDate);alert($('#ctl00_hdnCurrentDate').val());", true);
```

I have defined Hiddenfield in master page like

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnCurrentDate" runat="server" />
```

I got the alert of "hdnCurrentDate" is undefined. This is because I wrote the code in page load in not post back method.

Here is the other way what I have implemented.

I have used ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId in code behind. Here is the code for the same.

```
DateTime ClientDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime _localTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(ClientDateTime, "Arab Standard Time");
        return _localTime;
```

I didn't get destination time zone ID instead of "Arab standard Time". If I will get it, my problem will be solved.

Is there any other way to get the current date time in any of my page. I don't want to use Session and cookies.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how you have defined the hidden field in aspx page ?

Comment: '<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnCurrentDate" runat="server" />' It is my hidden field.

Comment: Have you checked my answer below ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is the javascript function to get client current datetime:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function GetDate(date) {
    CurTime = new Date(date);
    var offset = (new Date().getTimezoneOffset() / 60) * (-1);
    var utc = CurTime.getTime() + (offset * 60000 * (-1));
    var serverDate = new Date(utc + (3600000 * offset));
    var dateString = (serverDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + serverDate.getDate() + "/" +     
serverDate.getFullYear() + " " + serverDate.toLocaleTimeString("en-US", { hour12: true });
}
</script>
```

You can also get OffSet Time from code behind as below:

```
public static TimeSpan GetOffSetTime(string date)
    {
        DateTime d = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
        TimeZone zone = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone;
        TimeSpan local = zone.GetUtcOffset(d);
        return local;
    }
```

Comment: We need to add offset time in GMT time to get time of particular timezone.

Thanks. It will work for us.

Answer (score 2):

I have done this by using following way:

1. I have taken a `HiddenField` into the previous page where it requires :

   ```
   <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnTimeOffset" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" 
    Value="" />
   ```
2. Then, I am getting browser timezone by this :

   ```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
        $('#hdnTimeOffset').val(offset);

    });
   ```
3. I am getting time zone into a `Session` variable of the previous page, before redirecting to the next page, like on button click:

   ```
   protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Session["TimeOffset"] = hdnTimeOffset.Value;
       Response.Redirect("~/Root/abc.aspx");
   }
   ```
4. In the Main Page, I get the current time by using following code :

   ```
   DateTime dtmCurrentDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
   double dblMinutes =Convert.ToDouble(Session["TimeOffset"].ToString());                
   dtmCurrentDateTime = dtmCurrentDateTime.AddMinutes(-dblMinutes);
   ```

Comment: I will try for it. And let you know once done. Thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: Thanks Man this was helpful

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ASP.Net MVC use the following code

create a class "GetTime". and in this class you will find "Egypt Standard Time" you can pick your standard time zone from this list [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908343/list-of-timezone-ids-for-use-with-findtimezonebyid-in-c)

```
public class GetTime{
        public static DateTime GetCurrentTime()
        {
            DateTime serverTime = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime _localTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(serverTime, TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id, "Egypt Standard Time");
            return _localTime;
        }
    }
```

and in Global.asax add the line in the "Application_Start()"

```
GetTime.GetCurrentTime();
```

Then when you need to get the time you may write your code like this

```
var localTime = GetTime.GetCurrentTime();
var mytimeVarialbe = localTime.Hour;
```

and don't forget to import the class

```
 using yourproject.Folderthatcontainclass
```

Answer (score 0):

*'Is there any other way to get the current date time in any of my page. I don't want to use Session and cookies.'* **In that case** you can use JavaScript

Also, you don't need to use `RegisterStartupScript`. You can just call the `GetDate()` function in the `onLoad` event.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = function(){
        getDate();
    };

    function GetDate() 
    {
        var dt = new Date();
        var element = document.getElementById("MainContent_FormView1_Label1");

        element.text = dt.toDateString();
    }
</script>
```

However, you might want to read [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559150/best-practice-for-using-window-onload) for best practice in using `window.onload`, or consider using a framework such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and its [`document.ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: I have already implemented this code. But it is not working. Because server side page load execute first and then window.onload execute. So I couldn't get the value in page load.

Answer (score 0):

**Master Page**

set servertime

```
<asp:hiddenfield runat="server" id="HiddenField1"></asp:hiddenfield>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HiddenField1.Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

set client machine time

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function setvalue() {
            document.getElementById('HiddenField1').value = new Date();
        }
    </script>
   <body onload="setvalue();">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server"/>
    </div>
    </form>
    </body>
```

**Content Page**

```
HiddenField hdnvalue = this.Master.Master.FindControl("HiddenField1") as HiddenField;
string currenttime=hdnvalue.Value;
```

Comment: I don't want server current date and Time. This will give me server date and time.

Answer (score 0):

modified code from [This link:](http://forums.asp.net/p/1247758/2303034.aspx)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getDateTime()
{
    var localTime = new Date();
    var year= localTime.getYear();
    var month= localTime.getMonth() +1;
    var date = localTime.getDate();
    var hours = localTime .getHours();
    var minutes = localTime .getMinutes();
    var seconds = localTime .getSeconds();    
    //at this point you can do with your results whatever you please
}
</script>
```

At this point i would concatenate all of the fields together and put them in an asp:HiddenField control so they can be read on the server. On the server, call Convert.ToDateTime() on the Text value of your HiddenField.

if you don't use a masterpage you should try this.

```
HiddenField hdnFieldValue = (HiddenField)PreviousPage.FindControl("hdnField");
```

**Updated:**

Put a hidden field on the page.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidChild" runat="server"/>
```

in your javascript function

```
 var childHidden = document.getElementById('<%hidChild.ClientID%>');
 childHidden.value = window.opener.document.getElementById('text1').value;
```

Now access this hidden control on the page load event.

```
Response.Write(hidChild.Value); or Session["ParentVal"]=hidChild.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about use CulturalInfo From C# to get it?

> string currentFormat = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;

this will return "dd/MM/yy" or "dd/M/YYY" any format in client