# calling a javascript on page load

Tags: javascript, onload, states, maqetta

I am a newbie in js, so please forgive me if the question is elementary. I am designing a page in maqetta (maqetta.org) and enjoyed using states! the only question I have is it seems that the way it calls the states is as follows:
davinci.states.setState('state1')

for example in a button, it is defined a onclick proparty:
onclick="davinci.states.setState('state1')"

Now, my question is if i want to load my page in a different state than normal state what should I do?

I tried this:

```
<script> 
    window.onload=davinci.states.setState('state1')
</script>
```

but it did not work! I think it should be a very elemantry question but I could not find a solution for it! Can anybody help me on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```
window.onload = function(){
    davinci.states.setState('state1')
}
```

You may also want to refer
    http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp
    [Best practice for using window.onload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559150/best-practice-for-using-window-onload)
    https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onload