# How to enable geolocation in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

I got the HF HTML5 book , and when i reached to the chapter about geolocation and typed the code in , it doesn't work , i tried enabling the geo-location features in preferences but still no change , any suggestions?

The JS:

```
window.onload = getMyLocation;
    function getMyLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayLocation);
        } else {
            alert("Oops, no geolocation support");
    }
};

function displayLocation(position) {
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    var div = document.getElementById("location");
    div.innerHTML = "You are at Latitude: " + latitude + ", Longitude: " + longitude;
};
```

Problem was solved.

Comment: Show us the code... Btw, go [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp) and click `Try it`  -> it should work

Comment: I pasted the code in , and i already tried that , maybe i also have to put a button in , so that the browser asks me to enable it?

Comment: Have you tried w3schools link? Does that work? Btw, start your code with `window.onload = function() {`.

Comment: Yes :) it works ... i tried it yesterday and on another site too , it works but here not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that it's a bug from chrome , every file:// has it , you can't do it without a server like WAMP , or you can use an other browser.

Answer (score -1):

Try binding event handler like this:

```
window.onload = new function() { getMyLocation() };
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ozrentk/XkKpJ/) is the fiddle.

Comment: Wrong. This would call the event listener *before* the event occurred, on assignment. There is no syntax error, but the indentation is off.

Comment: That's not an error , and i found out that it's because you have to use a server or other browser , the file:// if bugged in chrome.

Comment: @PointedEars: thanks, I was clumsy. Answer updated from my existing project :)

Comment: @OzrenTkalčecKrznarić Your new code does not work. It would return a reference to a new, *non-callable* object and assign that to `window.onload`. An event listener must be *callable*. Also, it is still executing `getMyLocation()` before the event occurs, because you are calling the constructor *on assignment* already.

Comment: @aleksXPO You can either edit your question, hoping for a solution with `file://`, or post an answer to your own question.

Comment: @PointedEars: fiddle works fine. Question doesn't imply local file reference.

Comment: @OzrenTkalčecKrznarić Please read my updated comment and read a decent tutorial before you make further suggestions.

Comment: @PointedEars: It's a shame I have to repeat but it's still not in the question. The code is unobtrusive and has error in itself but semantics at least looks fine and code executes. For 'nice' onload binding see [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559150/best-practice-for-using-window-onload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559150/best-practice-for-using-window-onload).

Comment: @OzrenTkalčecKrznarić Both your RHS value and your timing are wrong. First the timing, then the value.

Comment: @PointedEars: Chrome/IE/FF shows no error in the fiddle. There is a standard and there is a real world. I repeat, my code is not 100% kosher but it works.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32635/discussion-between-ozren-tkalcec-krznaric-and-pointedears)