# Unable to change TextBox color?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, css

Here's a TextBox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="UsernameTextBox" runat="server" class="BlockInput"></asp:TextBox>
```

I wanna give an asp `textbox` some color but its not changing color

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     function BlockInput() {
         var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("BlockInput");
         for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
             elements[i].readOnly = true; // works
             elements[i].style.color = "#000000";// does not work!
         }
     }
     window.onload = BlockInput;
</script>
```

When I view source I could see the style being added:

```
<input name="ctl00$MainContent$UsernameTextBox" 
       type="text" id="MainContent_UsernameTextBox"
       class="BlockInput" readonly="" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
```

I also made sure nothing is overwriting the css.

Comment: Do you mean the face color or the background one?

Comment: Just a remark on best practice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559150/best-practice-for-using-window-onload

Comment: yes guys its the background im trying to change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
elements[i].style.color = "#000000";
```

to

```
elements[i].style.backgroundColor= "#000000";
```

hope this will help you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function BlockInput() {
var elements=document.getElementsByTagName('input');
         for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
             elements[i].readOnly = true; // works
             elements[i].style.backgroundColor= "#000000";
         }
     }
     window.onload = BlockInput;
</script>
```

Comment: It's backgroundColor and not background-color.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `elements` is undefined.
Do you want to make something like ? :

```
function BlockInput() {
         var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
         for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
             elements[i].readOnly = true; // works
             elements[i].style.color = "#000000";// does not work!
         }
     }
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y3Fv7/)**

Comment: Your answer was very close, TagName needed to be uppercase, but I will give you upvote

Answer (score 0):

With the color style you are setting the text color to black. If you want to change the background color of the textarea, try this:

```
elements[i].style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
```