# Vertical panel of images, want images to restart after last one

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am busy making a website for an architecture firm 
I have a `div` with 100% height position on the right, with images inside this div 
You can view this website [here](http://www.ysk.co.za/HLA/index.html) to see what I am talking about. 
The arrows under the div make the `margin-top` of the first `img` within the `div` `-135px` of what it currently is. (done using Javascript)
My goal is to try and make the images within the div continuos forever so that when that after the last image comes the first image again. (Obviously without having to copy and paste the images over and over again). 
The HTML for the `div`:

```
<div id="rightPanel">
    <div id="first" style="margin-top:0px;" onclick="changeF('url(images/bg1.jpg)')"><img src="images/thumb.jpg" width="170px" height="113px"></div>
    <div onclick="changeF('green')"><img width="170px" style="background:green;" height="113px"></div>
    <div onclick="changeF('yellow')"><img width="170px" style="background:yellow;" height="113px"></div>
    <div onclick="changeF('purple')"><img width="170px" style="background:purple;" height="113px"></div>
    <div onclick="changeF('red')"><img width="170px" style="background:red;" height="113px"></div>
    <div onclick="changeF('blue')"><img width="170px" style="background:blue;" height="113px"></div>
    <div onclick="changeF('aqua')"><img width="170px" style="background:aqua;" height="113px"></div>
    <div onclick="changeF('orange')"><img width="170px" style="background:orange;" height="113px"></div>
    <div onclick="changeF('yellow')"><img width="170px" style="background:yellow;" height="113px"></div>
    <div onclick="changeF('white')"><img width="170px" style="background:white;" height="113px"></div>
    <div onclick="changeF('gray')"><img width="170px" style="background:gray;" height="113px"></div>
    <div onclick="changeF('pink')"><img width="170px" style="background:pink;" height="113px"></div>
    <div onclick="changeF('yellow')"><img width="170px" style="background:yellow;" height="113px"></div>
    <div onclick="changeF('purple')"><img width="170px" style="background:purple;" height="113px"></div>
    <div onclick="changeF('red')"><img width="170px" style="background:red;" height="113px"></div>
    <div onclick="changeF('blue')"><img width="170px" style="background:blue;" height="113px"></div>
    <div onclick="changeF('aqua')"><img width="170px" style="background:aqua;" height="113px"></div>
    <div onclick="changeF('orange')"><img width="170px" style="background:orange;" height="113px"></div>
    <div onclick="changeF('violet')"><img width="170px" style="background:violet;" height="113px"></div>
    <div onclick="changeF('white')"><img width="170px" style="background:white;" height="113px"></div>
    <div onclick="changeF('black')"><img width="170px" style="background:black;" height="113px"></div>
</div>
```

Is there any method that would make this possible? 
Your answers are highly appreciated.

Comment: @RobSedgwick yes I do, do this of course, the `style="background:"` for those divs is just an exception so I do not have to assign a class / id to each one. Don't see how this could lead to me solving my problem?

Comment: @RobSedgwick I understand why it is bad for the CSS however those colours are temporary and will be replaced with images where I will not use inline css. However for the js how do I call a javascript function, with a different argument each time onclick without using the `onclick="function(argument)"` event listener. Is that not what it's there for?

Comment: or in `.html` -`<div data-color="green"></div>` - then in seperate `.js` - `$("div").click(function() { var color = $(this).attr("data-color") .. ` .. you tell me. Its all about code management. What if you you have 1 designer ( he doesn't want all that javascript and inline css ) and a separate front end developer ( he doesn't want all the markup ) - but even working alone - it's good and makes life easier.

Comment: Like I say, doesn't help you directly with the question, but will create a better way forward to solving many jobs like this in the future. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than shuffle the images up 135px, why not simply remove the top image and append it to the bottom?

```
var rightPanel = document.getElementById('rightPanel');
var images = rightPanel.getElementsByTagName('img');
var downButton = document.getElementById('downButton');
var upButton = document.getElementById('upButton');

downButton.onclick = function(){
    rightPanel.appendChild(images[0]);
}
upButton.onclick = function(){
    rightPanel.insertBefore(images[images.length-1],images[0]);
}
```

[Here's a simple jsFiddle to illustrate what I mean](http://jsfiddle.net/77kxh/).

Comment: Hi @Moob really appreciate your answer, it is exactly what I was looking for and works perfectly in jsFiddle, however was not working in my website, so I recreated (copy and pasted) it on a real HTML page here http://www.ysk.co.za/infiniteImg.html and still would not work, dont understand how it works in Jsfiddle but not on real HTML, any suggestions?

Comment: @YSK.CO Your `<script>` is in the `<head>` and is executed by the browser as soon as its loaded which is *before* the whole of the DOM has loaded. At the time the script runs the elements referenced in it do not yet exist. You could wrap the script in some kind of onLoad handler which waits for the whole page to fully load before calling the function but the easiest solution (effective across all browsers) is to move the script out of the `<head>` and  place as the last thing in the `<body>`.

Comment: If you must keep the script in the `<head>` you'll need to use `window.onload` to call the function. EG http://jsfiddle.net/77kxh/5/ but be aware that you can only have one such listener. See: [Best practice for using window.onload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559150/best-practice-for-using-window-onload) and [how to call a function when the page/dom is ready for it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-to-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-the)