# Run Function on default HTML Select with PHP And Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html-select

I try to Run Default Function on HTML Select, but Default Function doesn't works for Default Selected Value, But it Works On User Select

```
<?php
    $status_selected = 'A002';
?>
<!-- HTML Select 1 -->
<select id="state" class="l" name="state" onchange="Func()">
<option value="A001" <?php if($status_selected == "A001") echo "selected"; ?> data_item=" , StateA003 One, A003 State Two, A003 State Three">A001</option>
<option value="A002" <?php if($status_selected == "A002") echo "selected"; ?> data_item=" , A003 State One, A003 State Two, A003 State Three">A002</option>
<option value="A003" <?php if($status_selected == "A003") echo "selected"; ?> data_item=" , A003 State One, A003 State Two, A003 State Three">A003</option>
</select>
<!-- HTML Select 2 -->
<label for="city">Item : </label><select id="city" name="item" class="l"  onchange="onSelected()">
```

```
<script>
    function Func() {
        var city = document.getElementById('item');
        var state = document.getElementById('state');
        var val=state.options[state.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data_item');
        var arr=val.split(',');
        item.options.length = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if(arr[i] != "") {
                item.options[item.options.length] = new Option(arr[i],arr[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    function onSelected() {
        var item = document.getElementById('item').value;
        var state = document.getElementById('state').value;
        console.log('Parent : ' + state+ ', Item : ' + item);
    }
</script>
```

it load `HTML Select One` And then Select Item in `HTML Select Two`, But `HTML Select Two` Works Only By `Manual User Select` And Not Works For Default Programatically Value

Whole Of Codes Above Are On PHP File.

How i can fix it ?

Comment: what is Default Function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put Out Of PHP Tag:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

On Script Tag Put :

```
$(function() {
    $("#state").on("change", Func()); 
});
```

After :

```
item.options[item.options.length] = new Option(arr[i],arr[i]);
```

put the code :

```
$(item).prop("selectedIndex",i);
```

Comment: Yes, It Works, Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it is relevant, but maybe you want a [chained select](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained) box? If not, please clarify your question, it's very hard to follow.

---

EDIT: So the real issue is selecting the right option by code. In that case, this is a duplicate of [How do I programmatically set the value of a select box element using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78932/how-do-i-programmatically-set-the-value-of-a-select-box-element-using-javascript).

In your [onload script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559150/best-practice-for-using-window-onload)(or just after the functions if the script is at the bottom of the page), also run `Func()`, then set the value for `#city`:

```
Func();
var state = document.getElementById('state'),
    city = document.getElementById('city'),
    selectedCity = state.getAttribute('data-selected-city');
if(selectedCity) {
    city.value = selectedCity;
}
```

You need to store the selected city somewhere, my suggestion is to add it to the select:

```
<select id="state" data-selected-city="new-york">
<!--and so on--->
</select>
```

NOTE: setting a data attribute in HTML5 [should begin with `data-`](https://w3c.github.io/html/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes), not an underscore. So it's `data-item=""`, not `data_item=""`. That will give you a warning when running HTML validator.

Comment: thanks, but my issue is I want to choose Item  programmatically i can't find solution, but by user Selected it works well